# What does the nrows argument for from_records() do in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, open-source

I am trying to learn how to submit a Pull-Request to an open-source project.
So I chose the [issue #23455](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/23445) from pandas-dev. It is a simple documentation error. However I realized that I have no idea what the nrows actually does in from_records.

I tried

```
sales = [('Jones LLC', 150, 200, 50),
     ('Alpha Co', 200, 210, 90),
     ('Blue Inc', 140, 215, 95)]
labels = ['account', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(sales, columns=labels)
```

which yields

```
    account  Jan  Feb  Mar
0  Jones LLC  150  200   50
1   Alpha Co  200  210   90
2   Blue Inc  140  215   95
```

as the output. However to my understanding, if I do the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(sales, columns=labels,nrows=1)
```

I should only have one row in the df. Instead my output remains the same as the above df.

Can someone help me with this? Thank-you.

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: Try  `row = next(df.iterrows())[1]` before import itertools

Comment: There no documentation on it see https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/23445

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nrows` is a parameter used to select the first n elements of a record. If you see the code it currently only works on an iterator. There might be some reason why only on an iterator which I currently dont know.

An example to show the use case of nrows is to convert the sales data to an iterator. i.e

```
sales = iter([('Jones LLC', 150, 200, 50),('Alpha Co', 200, 210, 90), ('Blue Inc', 140, 215, 95)])

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(sales,nrows=2)
           0    1    2   3
0  Jones LLC  150  200  50
1   Alpha Co  200  210  90

sales = iter([('Jones LLC', 150, 200, 50),('Alpha Co', 200, 210, 90), ('Blue Inc', 140, 215, 95)])

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(sales,nrows=3)

           0    1    2   3
0  Jones LLC  150  200  50
1   Alpha Co  200  210  90
2   Blue Inc  140  215  95
```